# Is 25 $\rm kGy$ measured in Kerma or dose absorbed in material?

Tags: radiation, unit-conversion

I have been reading  [Trends in Radiation Sterilization of Health Care Products](https://www-pub.iaea.org/MTCD/Publications/PDF/Pub1313_web.pdf) form the IAEA.

They keep mentioning 25 [**kGy**] as the dose needed for sterilization (if you ctrl + f 25 kG you will get the results).

Some examples:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

I don't understand if this is quoted in [kerma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerma_(physics)) (dose aborbed by 1kg of air) or in absorbed dose of the material to be sterilizied?

Since for my dosimeters I use kerma, i want to understand if i need to apply a conversion or not

Comment: Logically, since the point is sterilization of material, these would be in absorbed dose in the material. Air kerma is used for for rad protection measurements to keep people safe in a space.

Comment: Yes i thought so too, however without it specifying it I wasn't sure. 
Thanks!